# difference between chrome apps and pc executable softwares

Tags: java, android, google-chrome-app

What is the difference between a chrome app and an executable software on my PC?

Comment: by the way what is chrome apps ? 
'Beginner'

Comment: Chrome apps are applications designed to function with your chrome platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is simple. The executables are built for a different runtime. Windows executables run on the Windows (win32) runtime, while Chrome Apps run on the operating system built by Google.

In order to run the executable you want on the desired platform, you could try setting up a virtual machine which will emulate that runtime environment.

Comment: Straightforward answer. Elaborating on my question then , why would I choose an app over an executable software? Is there a shift towards apps over executable ?

Comment: You should ask your question more clearly. You should decide, "How much users can run my executable on what environment?", For example I think more people are using Windows instead of Chrome. You could also built your application in Java for example to let it run on Chrome as well as Windows.

Comment: Thank you gi097 for your answer!